# How to read excel with several dataframes in one sheet and common index

Tags: python, pandas

I have an .xlsx file with several dataframes with common index in one sheet. An example:

[image]

What is a good way to load it and have two separate dataframes, one being first dataframe and second being second dataframe both with the same index as in the .xlsx file?

The results are:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [aa, aa, aa], 'col2': [bb, bb, bb], 'col3': [cc, cc, cc]}, index=[0,1,2])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [dd, dd, dd], 'col2': [ee, ee, ee], 'col3': [ff, ff, ff]},index=[0,1,2])
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
import pandas as pd

df0 = pd.read_excel('mybook.xlsx', header=[0,1])
df0.head()
```

outputs:

```
    Unnamed: 0_level_0    firstdataframe          seconddataframe
           index        col1    col2    col3    col1    col2    col3
0              0          aa    bb        cc    dd      ee      ff
1              1          aa    bb        cc    dd      ee      ff
2              2          aa    bb        cc    dd      ee      ff
```

so, multindex might help (header=[0,1] means first and second row is used as col index)

then,

```
df1=df0.loc[:,'firstdataframe']
df1
```

outputs

```
    col1    col2    col3
0     aa      bb    cc
1     aa      bb    cc
2     aa      bb    cc
```

and then,

```
df2=df0.loc[:,'seconddataframe']
df2
```

ouputs

```
    col1    col2    col3
0     dd      ee    ff
1     dd      ee    ff
2     dd      ee    ff
```

read https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the `usecols` parameter from `read_excel`
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html